# moved ld.so file and can not copy it back

Tags: ld

I have moved `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so` file to `/home/ubuntu/ld-2.24.so` and can not move it back. How to move or copy it back to `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so`. Thanks.

Comment: This comand should do the trick: `sudo mv /home/ubuntu/ld-2.24.so /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've moved the library that does the dynamic loading of programs, so pretty much nothing will work anymore on your system.  Fix this sort of issue by booting off an install media, and moving it back to the original location.

---

As was pointed out in the comments, there is still one statically linked program in /usr/bin and /sbin (these days /bin and /usr/sbin too), busybox, which would allow the mv command to work.

Comment: Back in the Old Days, binaries in `/sbin` were statically linked, and didn't require `ld.so`. YMMV. Any statically linked executable will still work. I agree that you have shot yourself in the foot (Power of Linux, applied without understanding).

Comment: ... if the statically-linked `busybox` is present on the system, then it might have been possible to use `busybox mv` rather than resorting to external media